# ElasticSearch join/combine two docs into one

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have ElasticSearch index which holds employee and their manager information. Each employee has an id, and each manager is also an employee, so managers have the same document structure as the employees. The only difference is that an employee will have a non-null managerId, whereas managers do not have managerId.

The simplified document structure is like the following:

```
Employeee document: { employeeId:1, ..., managerId:1234 , ..., name:.., address:..., etc...}
Manager document: {employeeId:1234, ..., managerId:null,...., name:.., address:..., etc...}
```

I usually search employees by their name or address, but I want the results include not only the employee details, but also their manager details, i.e., present the manager document as a new field into the employee search result.

So I expect the resulted JSON docs to be something like the following (see the newly added **managerDetails** field which holds all of the information about the manager) :

```
{ employeeId:1, ..., managerId:1234 , managerDetails:{employeeId:1234, ..., managerId:null,...., name:.., address:..., etc...},..., name:.., address:..., etc...},
{employeedId:...,...}
```

**Restriction:** I must say, I cannot change the indexed document structure.
**Potential Solution:** For each employee running two queries, one for the employee and one for the manager, and merging the results in application logic is not a solution for me, because there are millions of documents, and minimising the request number is crucial?

Comment: AFAIK you cant join ("present the manager document as a new field into the employee search result.") documents in ES unless it was defined with a join field type

Comment: Thank you @alexgids for your comment. Can you please elaborate the join field type, How can I define it?

Comment: join is basically creating a parent child relationship. You  can read more about it here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#parent-join